# How to determine source of water contaminant?

Tags: water

[image]

When the water drains it leaves a black oily residue that must be wiped/ washed with a sponge.  Cold water line  is not affected. The black oily liquid comes out only in hot water line, at tubs and sinks.  North Florida.

What is the likely cause of the oily residue?  Is there a simple and effective test to determine the source?  Water heater is dated 2014.  Is it impossible for the water heater to be the source of this problem?

## Update:

[image]

Comment: What items are in the line between cold supply and hot taps? Check each.

Comment: I see your updated photos and have edited my answer below. The sharkbite hoses you have pictured have had a class action lawsuit filed for the reason I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am confident that the problem is one of two things:

1. Braided flexible supply lines. Either with [stainless steel braiding](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BPORPI) or with a [black plastic braiding](https://www.lowes.com/pd/BrassCraft-24-in-L-3-4-in-FIP-Inlet-x-3-4-in-Outlet-Braided-PVC-Water-Heater-Connector/3152149). These are garbage products made with little to no quality control in China even though they are branded with formerly American-manufacturers' names like Brasscraft or Fluidmaster. The rubber internals deteriorate from hot water over just a couple of years and result in the water contamination that you are seeing. With the quantity of contamination you are seeing, my guess is that your problem is the hoses, not the second problem posted below.

The solution is to replace your supply lines with corrugated stainless steel or copper supply lines. These do not have a rubber liner.

2. [Deteriorating dielectric nipples.](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Utilitech-2-Pack-Water-Heater-Dielectric-Nipples/3693216) Again, the source of the problem here is low-quality rubber sourced in China. The dielectric nipples use black rubber valves inside that deteriorate over just a few years.

The solution is to replace the dielectric nipples.

**EDIT**: the OP updated the post with a photo showing a sharkbite water supply hose. Just as I thought! These hoses have [had a class action lawsuit filed](https://www.classaction.org/news/home-depot-reliance-worldwide-corp.-facing-class-action-over-defective-sharkbite-push-to-connect-hoses) because of the deteriorating rubber.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have an anaerobic bacterial colony growing in the pipes. Does the water smell like sulfur? Does this happen at all sinks? If so, you need to introduce bleach into the plumbing somehow. There are a variety of ways to do this. Maybe at the water heater (if flex connectors), You'll need a small electric pump, disconnect the hot water line and with appropriate fittings and adapters, connect it to the pump,   You'll need a clean (NEW) garbage can that you can put about 20 gallons of water in and a couple of gallons of bleach. Turn on the pump, open all the hot water valves and let it run until you get a bleach smell from each faucet. Maybe also run the dishwasher. The turn it all off and let it set for at least 4 hours.   You'll probably need a new flex connection for the WH as they don't usually seal well once disconnected.

After reconnecting the WH, if you had a anaerobic colony, when you flush your system from the bleach, you will probably see almost completely black water coming out of your faucets, you may even need to remove and clean the aerators.

I've fought this problem for a few years at my house but I think I finally got it nailed, we haven't had an infection for 5 years or so.

AND SORRY....but I may be completely wrong here, and stmp945 might have the right answer.   Bottom line:  If it smells like sulfur, you've probably got an aerobic colony that you need to deal with.